# RoR4: Integer Validation

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've noticed a strange behavior when validating multiple integers inside one model.
I'm using `Ruby 2.0.0` and `Rails 4.0`

Imagine I have four integers: i1, i2, i3 and i4. 
I'm validating them with these rules:

```
validates :i1, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 1..3 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }
validates :i2, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 1..3 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }
validates :i3, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 1..3 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }
validates :i4, allow_blank: true, length: { in: 1..3 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Now When setting i1, i2, i3 and i4 to nil and saving the record, Rails throws me a `"rollback transaction"-message` and does not save the record. When I look for record.errors, no errors are listed. When I set the last integer listed in the validation (in this case i4) to some integer (0 to X), all validations pass and the record gets saved.

Same happens when I'm using only 3 integers in my model and setting the first two integers to nil and the last one (that time i3) to some integer.

Why is that so? That is not how it is supposed to function, is it? The validations say that the integers should nothing but integers. Even though they seem to be valid if they're `nil` when the last integer listed in the validations is `not nil`.

I know there are ugly work arounds, but I would like to have everything clean in my project.

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian

**Edit**

The exact message returned is nothing more than this:

```
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

If I type in *record.errors* into the console, there's just an empty string inside of @messages:

```
<record data>, @messages={}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact `message` it said?

Comment: change the length from 0..3